# Can I set a State in map function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function

This is my part of my Code that get json api from backend and rendering as list.

This is my json data example

```
(15) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {id: 1, title: '1번', content: null, createTime: '2021-10-17T14:07:02', updateTime: '2021-10-17T14:07:02', …}
1: {id: 2, title: '2번', content: null, createTime: '2021-10-17T14:07:02', updateTime: '2021-10-17T14:07:02', …}
2: {id: 3, title: '3번', content: null, createTime: '2021-10-17T14:07:02', updateTime: '2021-10-17T14:07:02', …}
3: {id: 4, title: '1번', content: null, createTime: '2021-10-17T14:07:02', updateTime: '2021-10-17T14:07:02', …}
4: {id: 5, title: '2번', content: null, createTime: '2021-10-17T14:07:02', updateTime: '202
```

And this is my question below

```
 const [postId, setPostId] = useState();



  return (
    <Container>
      {list?.map((post, idx) => (
        <Content key={idx} onClick={openModal}>
          {post.id}
          {() => setPostId(post.id)}
          {post.title}
        </Content>
      ))}

      <Modal data={postId} state={modalState} closeModal={closeModal} />
      <div ref={observer} />
      <div>{isLoading ? <Loading /> : "Data END"} </div>
    </Container>
  );
}

export default Posts
```

I want to set

```
setPostId
```

using value of

```
{post.id}
```

in map function
but I don't know how to do that?
and

```
{() => setPostId(post.id)}
```

this function is not working

help me plz

Comment: have you tried just ```{setPostId(post.id)}```  instead of ```{() => setPostId(post.id)}``` ? or you can just call setPostId(post.id)  just before returning JSX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do -

```
{
  list?.map((post, idx) => {
    setPostId(post.id);
    return (
      <Content key={idx} onClick={openModal}>
        {post.id}
        {post.title}
      </Content>
    );
  });
}
```

But I'm not sure why you want to do it this way...

Answer (score 1):

map can't change the state of the array because it return a new array with the new state, if you want to change the some data in the array itself you need to use `list.forEach` instead